# oracle dbms_scheduler.create_job() error when executed within stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, dbms-scheduler

Creating job from anonymous block is working fine:

```
begin
  SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.create_job(
  job_name    =>     'test_job',
  job_type    =>     'PLSQL_BLOCK',
  job_action  =>     'begin null; end;',
  enabled     =>     TRUE,
  auto_drop   =>      TRUE);
end;
```

Result:

> PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Creating job from stored procedure:

```
create or replace procedure pr_create_job is
begin
  SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.create_job(
  job_name =>'test_job',
  job_type =>'PLSQL_BLOCK',
  job_action =>'begin null; end;',
  enabled     => TRUE,
  auto_drop   => TRUE);
end pr_create_job;

Begin
  pr_create_job;
End;
```

Result:

> Error report - ORA-27486: insufficient privileges ORA-06512: at
>   "SYS.DBMS_ISCHED", line 135 ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER", line
>   271 ORA-06512: at "PR_CREATE_JOB", line 3 ORA-06512: at line 2
>   27486. 00000 -  "insufficient privileges"

Comment: Probably because privilege to use `dbms_scheduler` is granted to the user  through a role. It should be granted directly to the user.

Comment: Thank you, CREATE JOB privilege was granted through a role.

Answer (score 0):

As [Kaushik Nayak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7998591/kaushik-nayak) mentioned, CREATE JOB privilege was granted through a role and not directly to the user, granting directly to user solved this error.